# jQuery Ajax character issue with IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, encoding

I am facing a strange problem. I am posting some data using jQuery Ajax method.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/Member/GetPagedResult?page=1'
                + '&company=' + $('#CompanyName').val().trim()
                + '&member=' + $('#MemberLastName').val().trim()
                + '&regionID=' + $('#SelectedRegionID').val()
                + '&year=' + $('#SelectedAwardYear').val(),
```

But in MVC controller when posting some Latin characters(ôté) from Chrome I am getting correct value, but when it is from IE getting some special characters instead of right value. Please see the screenshot below. I tried setting contentType 'application/json; accept-charset=UTF-8' but not working

How can I get the correct value in MVC from all browsers?

[image]

Comment: Try it like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/ys9p99wt/